# nginx as PHP service entrypoint

Tags: php, nginx

## Question

The main question here - how to serve static assets included with `/vendor/` prefix in URL with separate `nginx` config location?

Desired behavior is - `nginx` as root entrypoint that apply `SSL` certificate, then it serve static assets and *all* other requests are handled by `php` interpreter.

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions in one. Someone will be searching the same issue but your question will be very messy for a specific cases.

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii, ok. What about discussion topic?

Comment: You'll have to code `rewrite rules` in nginx configuration, you redirect all requests to you front controller, except static files like css, jss, ...

Comment: Can you include your current nginx config. This sounds like all you need to do is add a `try_files` directive to one of your `location` blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with a simple config like:

```
location / {
    # This is cool because no PHP is touched for static content.
    # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/example.com.sock;
}
```

But if you want to get ultimate performance, see [this article on `try_files` drawbacks](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-try_files-is-evil-too) and how to configure NGINX without it.